# Group segments which are not overlapping and keep the good order

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am trying to solve an interesting problem (I will code it in JavaScript, but doesn't really matter):

Let's say there are multiple videos as segments of few seconds on different y layers.
If videos overlaps in time then the one which is in the top layer will be visible when playing all of them at the same time.

Now, I have a lot of this layers (this is the problem) I want to merge some layers when possible 
so at the end I will have same number of videos visually displayed in the same way, but less layers.

I will show you an image which will give a better understanding

[image]

In this image I took an example of 11 videos, on 11 initial layers.

For example we can see that 2 and 1 can be put on the same layer since they do not overlap and visually the videos will be displayed the same, but for instance 1 and 9 cannot be put together neighter on the 9th layer nor on 1st layer since 7 overaps and  will lose the display order (z-index)

If I want to represent this in code:

```
const orderedSegments = [
  [15, 18],     // 1
  [0.3, 9],     // 2
  [4, 13],      // 3
  [8, 14],      // 4
  [1, 3],       // 5
  [16, 19.5],   // 6
  [4.1, 17.5],  // 7
  [0, 2.9],     // 8
  [2.9, 11],    // 9
  [12.5, 19.4], // 10
  [11.3, 12]    // 11
]
```

And here is how can look one of possible result which will have only 5 layers but with the same display:

```
 const expectedLayers = [
      [[0.3, 9], [15, 18]],                  // 2, 1
      [[1, 3], [4, 13]],                     // 5, 3
      [[8, 14], [16, 19.5]],                 // 4, 6
      [[0, 2.9], [4.1, 17.5]],               // 8, 7
      [[2.9, 11], [11.3, 12], [12.5, 19.4]]  // 9, 11, 10
 ]
```

I have thought to sort the segments by the start duration and then to create 1 layer and try to insert into it as much as possible and when not possible anymore to create a new layer... but I'm not sure how to preserve correctly the order.

So that's why I'm asking to see if there are maybe some known algorithms to do such things like merging segments while preserving order.

Thanks for your ideas.

Comment: Are you looking for the optimal solution (fewest possible layers - which is hard) or just best-effort?

Comment: What do you mean by "preserve the order"? That the layers of two segments that overlap each other are never inverted, i.e. the same one is displayed on the top?

Comment: As first version I'm not looking for fewest possible.  By keep visual order I mean if before merging one layer was visible above another, then after merging this sould not change

Comment: I wouldn't start with sorting, which does mess with the order as you observed. Rather, iterate segments from top to bottom, and move them into the highest layer above that they will fit in without colliding with another segment on the way there.

Comment: To find such collisions easily, the segments in each layer would be sorted indeed.

Comment: @Bergi at the beginning you have only one segment per layer! so no sorting per layer needed.

Comment: your approach top -> bottom seems interesting, I will think about it

Comment: What is the problem with 5 - 3 - 6 instead of 5 - 3 ..? Can it be like (2,1), (5,3,6), (8,4), (7), (9,11,10)..?

Comment: @Redu nothing is wrong, this is another solution :) There are multiple possible solutions to this problem. Your solution like mine has 5 layers at the end. Interesting would be to code this and find the best solution. (meaning less possible layers) which does not seem easy. That's why I'm trying to do something good as first version, not optimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that you call your segments `orderedSegments` when in fact, they aren't.
So, to remove any confusion, I decided to rename them to `unOrderedSegments` and then create a separate `orderedSegments` array that has some logic about which segments should come first.

I then wrote a little helper function `isOverlapping(a, b)` which looks at two segments and decides if they intersect/overlap each other or not.

Then I created a `layers` array that will hold each layer as a separate element (array of segments).

The logic is simple as described in the pseudo code:

```
loop through each `segment` in `orderedSegments`:
    loop through each `layer` in `layers`:
        check if the `segment` is overlaping any of the segments in the current `layer'
        if not then insert the `segment` to the current `layer`
        if yes, then check with the other layers
        if we reach the end of layers but could not insert it in any,
           then add the segment to its own new layer
```

```js
const unOrderedSegments = [
  [15, 18], // 1
  [0.3, 9], // 2
  [4, 13], // 3
  [8, 14], // 4
  [1, 3], // 5
  [16, 19.5], // 6
  [4.1, 17.5], // 7
  [0, 2.9], // 8
  [2.9, 11], // 9
  [12.5, 19.4], // 10
  [11.3, 12], // 11
];

const orderedSegments = unOrderedSegments.sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0]);

const isOverlapping = (a, b) => {
  const check1 = a[0] > b[0] && a[0] < b[1];
  const check2 = b[0] > a[0] && b[0] < a[1];

  return check1 || check2;
};

const layers = [];

for (let i = 0; i < orderedSegments.length; i++) {
  const currentSegment = orderedSegments[i];

  let inserted = false;

  for (let j = 0; j < layers.length; j++) {
    const currentLayer = layers[j];
    let canBeInserted = true;
    for (let k = 0; k < currentLayer.length; k++) {
      const segment = currentLayer[k];

      if (isOverlapping(segment, currentSegment)) {
        canBeInserted = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (canBeInserted) {
      currentLayer.push(currentSegment);
      inserted = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (!inserted) {
    layers.push([currentSegment]);
  }
}

// print each layer on a spearate line 
// ( convert array to string )
layers.forEach((layer) => {
  let layerString = "";
  layer.forEach((segment) => {
    layerString += `[${segment[0]}-${segment[1]}]`;
  });
  console.log(layerString);
});
```

Comment: What I call ordered segments, they are ordered by layer :) but not SORTED by time. I will check your code this evening, thx for the answer

Comment: I ended up doin something similar, but I don't need to sort them at the end :) 
Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 1):

```
const orderedSegments = [
  [15, 18],     // 1
  [0.3, 9],     // 2
  [4, 13],      // 3
  [8, 14],      // 4
  [1, 3],       // 5
  [16, 19.5],   // 6
  [4.1, 17.5],  // 7
  [0, 2.9],     // 8
  [2.9, 11],    // 9
  [12.5, 19.4], // 10
  [11.3, 12]    // 11
]

// sort array by starting time (orderedSegments[i][0])
orderedSegments.sort((a, b) => {
  if(a[0] < b[0]) return -1;
  if(a[0] > b[0]) return 1;
  return 0;
});

const newSegments = [];
while(orderedSegments.length > 0) {
  // get first element of array
  let element = orderedSegments[0];
  // all "used" items will be removed. used items are marked with -1
  if(element[0] == -1) {
    orderedSegments.shift();
    break;
  }
  // newElementGroup represents a new layer
  let newElementGroup = [];
  newElementGroup.push(element);
  for(let i = 0; i < orderedSegments.length; i++) {
    if(orderedSegments[i][0] > element[1]) {
      element = orderedSegments[i].slice();
      newElementGroup.push(element);
      // mark element as "used"
      orderedSegments[i][0] = -1;
    }
  }
  newSegments.push(newElementGroup);
  // remove first element after creating a new layer until orderedSegments is empty
  orderedSegments.shift();
}

newSegments.forEach(element => console.info(element))
```

i guess that should do the trick

Comment: could you please explain in few words how is this working? the idea behide this...

Comment: i've added some comments to the source code. this code will rearrange the layers, so some layers will be in a different place after merging.